# React Convert Hooks To Class But Get Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, react-hooks, jsx

I want to convert react hooks component to class component but I get error.

**HOOKS**

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const refValt = useRef(null);

  const myfuncValt = () => {
    console.log("222222222222222222222");
  };


  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      refValt.current.click();
    }, 5000); //miliseconds
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <div ref={refValt} onClick={myfuncValt}>Valt</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**CLASS**

```
import React  from "react";

const myfuncValt = () => {
  console.log("222222222222222222222");
};

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const refValt = React.createRef(null);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.refValt.current.click();
    }, 5000);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div ref={this.refValt} onClick={myfuncValt}>
          Valt
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I get this error =

[image]

I try this.refValt.click(); But It doesn't working.

Actually I suspect the differences between createref vs useref.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
const refValt = React.createRef(null);
```

... needs to be this:

```
this.refValt = React.createRef(null);
```